# Wishing to be dead without committing suicide

Tags: mental-health, depression, disorders, suicide

Trying to commit suicide is a mental disorder if it's due to depression and alike. But- Is there a medical disorder where one wishes to be dead, without ever taking action (i.e. doing harm to oneself). Is that still classified as depression?

Comment: That's a question for a qualified therapist.

Comment: Hi Singh, this is a very good question but doesn't belong on this site, as we can't give advice. I recommend asking a counselor who can better explain and guide understanding.

Comment: While personal medical advice is outside the scope of Health SE, the line between personal disappointment and suicidal ideation due to a mental disorder can be very thin, which is why any case approaching this line is a far better fit for a licensed psychiatrist/psychologist/counselor than for random folks on the internet

Comment: @DoctorWhom Maybe we misread the Q with the trigger word as *a* "case" (which it might be). However, I feel that this might be salvageable when reworded into really general territory of mental health. Worth a try or still off-topic then?

Comment: @DoctorWhom I think the question is interesting, and it's core is about depression: is it a "full depression" when one considers one's own death as a relief, without every doing harm to oneself?

Comment: Suicidality, aka "suicidal ideation," can be conceptualized as a spectrum from thoughts about not existing (sometimes termed "passive suicidal ideation") to visualizing and making plans, to active attempts.  The risk for completing suicide increases when someone has a plan or previous attempt, but it still happens even with people with seemingly benign thoughts of being dead.  Many people have passive thoughts at some point in life, but I cannot in good conscious say there is any point where there is no concern someone will act on it. Depression is associated with ALL degrees of suicidality

Comment: from passive ideation to completion, and it doesn't necessarily correlate with the severity of depression.  Depression itself is somewhat of a spectrum.  The PHQ 2 screening tool helps catch it, and PHQ 9 defining tool helps categorize severity.  But even falling below the cutoff line of symptoms for diagnosis still can be considered depressive symptoms (or DSM-speech depression NOS) if they impact the person's life.

Comment: I think the way he wrote the question is not quite clear, but he is likely asking whether thoughts of wanting to be dead means someone is definitely depressed or whether someone can have thoughts of wanting to be dead without being depressed.  I'm not sure there is a safe generic answer to this question, and it can only be answered on an INDIVIDUAL case-by-case basis.  So I vote that it stay closed.

Comment: None of the comments make sense to me. My question was whether thinking about suicide a mental disordered. As Dave mentioned in the answer, it is not a mental illness. It's due to the lack of coping skills. This makes sense. When I get angry or extremely frustrated, I don't know how to handle it. So I imagine and plan (research ways to die) killing myself, which makes me cry thus easing my frustration. So, that's what I was trying to figure out: is this way of handling a situation a mental illness. I am terrible at putting together my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Self-harm is not a mental illness, but a behavior that indicates a
>   lack of coping skills. Several illnesses are associated with it,
>   including borderline personality disorder, depression, eating
>   disorders, anxiety or posttraumatic distress disorder.

[National Alliance on Mental Health](https://www.nami.org/learn-more/mental-health-conditions/related-conditions/self-harm)

> Sometimes when people self-harm, they feel on some level that they
>   intend to die. Over half of people who die by suicide have a history
>   of self-harm.
>
> However, the intention is more often to punish themselves, express
>   their distress or relieve unbearable tension. Sometimes the reason is
>   a mixture of both.
>
> Self-harm can also be a cry for help.

[NIH](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/self-harm/)

So the thought of wishing oneself dead *could* be construed as a symptom of depression, but **cannot be classified as depression until a professional takes a closer look at the individual's life, behavior, and thought patterns**.

This is because the thought of self-harm might be, in a way, self-harming already, which may be a way to feel control, release, or some particular stimulus, or it could be the initial stages of depression, or so on. The ambiguity can also be witnessed in all the comments going back in forth in the OP's question.

Therefore, it's a complicated area, extremely broad, but with a general consensus in one area: best to consult a professional or someone trusted to gain more information and insight into the matter.

Comment: It might profit this answer if some aspects of the *volatile* comments were included here. Touchy issues in general, maybe touchy issue in this "case".

Comment: Hmm... there's a lot of good information in those comments. I'll need time to find references.

Comment: This answers my question. When I wish to die, or imagine killing myself, it's due to the lack of coping skills. When I feel frustrated or angry, it is my way of letting it out and then feeling pity for myself. I think that calms me down (maybe by taking mind away from the issue). The current edited version of my original question is not what I was asking at all. But I am glad your answer answered my original question (which may have been unclear the way I originally wrote it). Also, I can assure that I do not feel depression.

Comment: Narusan tried to reword the question to be more general, because we don't address personal-diagnosis type questions. That was probably why it was voted to be closed at first. Glad this was helpful though, hope things improve.

Comment: Read the definition of depression @Singh before you say that. It's not always feeling down/depressed, there are other manifestations of depression.  I would not write off thoughts of wanting to die as a harmless coping method -  - especially if you are reading about plans how to do it.  You need to learn more advanced coping skills anyways, so why not talk with a counselor about this.

Comment: People aren't usually good at diagnosing themselves, I agree with DoctorWhom. Best to be safe and talk to a friendly professional about it.